# how can I generate SIMO underwater acoustic channel

Tags: matlab, estimation, equalization

I'm working in underwater acoustic channel, then I need to generate SIMO channel to use it for simulation in MATLAB,  how can I generate SIMO channel?

thank you

Comment: Deep/Shallow/Littoral? Winter/Summer? Frequency? Reciprocal? Sea State?

Comment: Hello. thank you for your reply ..  for sahllow, summers,Fc=30000; Fs=102400; not Reciprocal; ofdm, length 32 taps. SIMO 4 Rx antennas.

Comment: If the above data are still not enough ...  could you please share the guide and I will try to understand it and change everything according to my code..

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz  please your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the literature is small, the Oceans are large.  There is a large variation in physical detail.  Unlike RF, there are no ITU standard models. A serious effort really requires real data, You can spend 20 years refining a model.

You could start by looking at,

> Stojanovic, Milica, and James Preisig. "Underwater acoustic
>   communication channels: Propagation models and statistical
>   characterization." IEEE Communications Magazine 47.1 (2009): 84-89.

At 100Khz, a ray tracing model should be adequate and you can get ray models at Porter's Ocean Acoustic Library at:

http://oalib.hlsresearch.com/

Ray shooting can require a lot of trial and error to get eigenrays. At short ranges, an iso-velocity range independent model might be adequate.  Most models are Fortran, not Matlab, but you can call them from Matlab. If you look around the web, particularly those of Australian establishments , there is code with tighter MATALB integration.  Most prop code is deterministic.  Ira Dyer is a pioneer is random propagation, so papers that cite him, might be useful, and you can do that using Google Scholar. If you can read Russian, a lot of their literature is very good.

Noise models are local but at 100KHz, noise sources are going to be near.

Projector and forward volume scattering effects are hard to model. Without data, you need to make some guesses.

Comment: Thank you so much ..  yes but what we usually make, we use Bellhop to generate just the channel and then start implement our work based on it. but I don't have a guide for that to generate new SIMO channel. . . do you have such source code for time equalizers for underwater acoustic channel? thanks again.

Comment: Nothing I can share